# Django ORM: Getting rows based on max value of a column

Tags: sql, django, greatest-n-per-group, django-orm

I have a class Marketorders which contains information about single market orders and they are gathered in snapshots of the market (represented by class Snapshot). Each order can appear in more than one snapshot with the latest row of course being the relevant one.

```
class Marketorders(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    snapid = models.IntegerField()
    orderid = models.IntegerField()
    reportedtime = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    ...


class Snapshot(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    ...
```

What I'm doing is getting all of the orders across several snapshots for processing, but I want to include only the most recent row for each order. In SQL I would simply do:

```
SELECT m1.* FROM marketorders m1 WHERE reportedtime = (SELECT max(reportedtime)  
FROM marketorders m2 WHERE m2.orderid=m1.orderid);
```

or better yet with a join:

```
SELECT m1.* FROM marketorders m1 LEFT JOIN marketorders m2 ON 
m1.orderid=m2.orderid AND m1.reportedtime < m2.reportedtime 
WHERE m2.orderid IS NULL;
```

However, I just can't figure out how to do this with Django ORM. Is there any way to accomplish this without raw SQL?

EDIT: Just to clarify the problem. Let's say we have the following marketorders (leaving out everything unimportant and using only orderid, reportedtime):

```
1, 09:00:00
1, 10:00:00
1, 12:00:00
2, 09:00:00
2, 10:00:00
```

How do I get the following set with the ORM?

```
1, 12:00:00
2, 10:00:00
```

Comment: I'm not an expert with Django's, but there are few ORMs that can cope with a dependent subquery or null-self-join. It's expected that sometimes you will have to drop down to SQL to put an efficient query together.

Comment: I'm hoping that is not the case with Django. =) I've been trying to do this with the extra lookups, but I can't figure out how to reference the original orderid from the extra call (so yeah, might be that dependent subqueries are not possible with extra lookups). I'm somewhat new to Django so it might also be that I just don't know how to write such references.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood right you need a list of Marketorder objects that contains each Marketorder with highest reportedtime per orderid

Something like this should work (disclaimer: didn't test it directly):

```
m_orders = Marketorders.objects.filter(id__in=(
    Marketorders.objects
        .values('orderid')
        .annotate(Max('reportedtime'))
        .values_list('id', flat=True)
))
```

For documentation check:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

Edit:
This should get a single Marketorder with highest reportedtime for a specific orderid

```
order = (
    Marketorders.objects
        .filter(orderid=the_orderid)
        .filter(reportedtime=(
            Marketorders.objects
                .filter(orderid=the_orderid)
                .aggregate(Max('reportedtime'))
                ['reportedtime__max']
        ))
)
```

Comment: Actually your first assumption was correct. I'm looking for a way to get a set of orders that contains only the newest row for each orderid (i.e. filter out the older "instances" of the orders).

Your first solution is pretty close to what I'm trying to do (don't know why I didn't think of doing subqueries like that), but this only seems to return the first order of the subset, not the newest one.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have a good reason why you don't use [ForeignKey](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) or (in your case better) [ManyToManyField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield). These fields represent the relational structure of ur models.

Furthermore it is not necessary to declare an pk-field id. if no pk is defined, django adds id.

The code below allow orm-queries like this:

```
   m1 = Marketorder()
   m1.save() # important: primary key will be added in db
   s1 = Snapshot()
   s2 = Snapshot()
   s1.save()
   s2.save()
   m1.snapshots.add(s1)
   m1.snapshots.add(s2)
   m1.snapshots.all()
   m1.snapshots.order_by("id") # snapshots in relations with m1 
                               # ordered by id, that is added automatically
   s1.marketorder_set.all()    # reverse
```

*so for your query*:

```
snapshot = Snapshot.objects.order_by('-id')[0] # order desc, pick first
marketorders = snapshot.marketorder_set.all()  # all marketorders in snapshot
```

*or compact*:

```
marketorders = Snapshot.objects.order_by('-id')[0].marketorder_set.all()
```

*models.py*:

```
class Snapshot(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Marketorder(models.Model):
    snapshots = models.ManyToManyField(Snapshot)
    reportedtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
```

By convention all model classes name are singular. Django makes it plural in different places automatically.

[more on queries (filtering, sorting, complex lookups)](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/). a must-read.

Comment: As to the keys and conventions, that's true. My database is a legacy one and the model was automatically created from it so it doesn't follow all Django conventions. I've been adding the correct references as I go, but haven't really bothered with changing names.